# Проблема с получением почты через Outlook на терминальном сервер, куда копать?

Tags: terminal, outlook

Добрый день. 
Ситуация следующая: хост гипервизор esxi 5.5 на нем крутится 3 ВМ :2 терминала и DC.
На одном из терминалов наблюдается **проблема с получением почты**. Используем Outlook 2013, хостинг почты находится на яндексе используем протоуол IMAP. 
Наблюдается ситуация в почтовом клиенте при ""Отправить и получить" ничего в ящик не падает, **приходиться открыть закрыть outlook** и после этого на некоторый короткий период начнут приходить письма. Если смотреть через любой браузер то все в порядке, все письма видны и отправляются. 
В логих винды один раз где-то месяц назад замечал что предупреждение было и источник tcp. Но как-то не обратил пристального внимания. Видимо вон оно и вылезло.

Outlook 15.0.46.93.1000 x32

Windows Server 2012r2 (версия 6.3 сборка 9600)

Буду весьма благодарен любым попыткам решить данную проблему.